# Making a concept or a view "more present"

Tags: single-word-requests, social-interaction

Is there a word or expression for the process of making a concept, an index or a view more present? That is, in people's minds and in the public or social sphere?

Notes:

- I'm interested in a word describing the result rather than the effort (i.e. not "promoting" the idea).
- It's not about more people subscribing to your idea, it's about it being "out there" - noticed, discussed, debated etc.
- It's not that this idea, or notion, is unknown. It is known, as something vague, and obscure. People know of it, but don't know it well.

Comment: Can you give an example of how this word would be used?

Comment: @Barmar: Hmm. I'm trying to translate an official document from Hebrew describing the stated objectives of an association, which are, among other things, the promotion and the "making-more-present" of certain political views.

Comment: That's not very helpful. Can you edit your question and include a sentence with a blank for the word?

Answer (score 3):

The most common and idiomatic way of phrasing this concept in English is to say ***raising awareness***.

For example, the advocacy arm of the  [Pacific Water Commission defines *raising awareness*](http://www.pacificwater.org/userfiles/file/IWRM%20Training%20ppts/Raising%20awareness%20final.pdf) thus:

> ***Raising awareness*** is communicating something that **changes the way people perceive the world** and therefore changes the way they think and act.

The drawback to the phrase is that it's *so* common that it has become cliche. You know you've lost your edge as a turn of phrase when you become the subject of  *New Yorker* cartoon:

[image: New Yorker cartoon on the vapidity of easing awarenes]

<sub>Sociological side-note: you might be interested to learn that "raising awareness" often has the *opposite* of the intended effect; see [*Awareness Is Overrated* from *NY Magazine*](http://nymag.com/scienceofus/2014/07/awareness-is-overrated.html).</sub>

Comment: Since he asked for the end result, not the action, I think _awareness_ or _raised awareness_ would be the answer here.

Comment: @Barmar  why did he write in his question that he wanted a word or expression for the process of making a concept, an index or a view more present? IMHO the question was poorly formulated. The author doesn't know what he wants. In addition, he doubts that visibility can relate to the abstract things. See comments to your own answer. )))

Comment: Yeah, I would still appreciate it if he added an example use case to the question.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase that comes to my mind is **increased (or greater) [visibility](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/visibility)**.

> The degree to which something has attracted general attention; prominence:

The synonym **prominence** found in that definition can also be used.

Comment: Can you increase the visibility of something abstract? Which is not even an abstract definition of a phenomenon visible today? :-(

Comment: I think you can. Of course, it's metaphorical visibility, but most ways of describing abstract notions involve metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

OP’s request is somewhat contradictory, first asking for “a word or expression for **the process** of making ...” but then noting that their interest is focused on "a word describing **the result** rather than the effort [process]."

As other users have mentioned the process involves, dissemination, raising awareness, imprinting ... in general, promoting a concept. The effect of those *efforts* may be to make an obscure or little known concept less abstract and more ... **tangible** and/or **accessible**.

> [**tangible**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tangible) adjective:
>
> **2**: capable of being precisely identified or realized by the mind  (Merriam-Webster *online*)
>
> [**accessible**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessible) *adjective*:
>
> **4**: capable of being used or seen: available
>
> **5**: capable of being understood or appreciated   (Merriam-Webster *online*)

Answer (score 0):

***Dissemination*** as defined by Google: *the act of spreading something, especially information, widely; circulation*.

Comment: he said he wants a word for the result, not the act.

Comment: Dissemination of political views can be regarded as a result. There is a greater dissemination of this view on account of this association.

Comment: I'd say this suggests making more people subscribe to this view or idea. Or am I getting the nuance wrong?

Comment: @einpoklum I don't think there's any implication that greater dissemination of an idea means greater acceptance of it. Obviously there will be a correlation, so there is some unavoidable implication, but dissemination specifically refers to a *spread of* (information or such). Think of it like spreading seeds--they may or may not develop into plants.

Answer (score 0):

South Carolina raised the Confederate battle flag over the state capitol to **imprint** the idea of the noble struggle of the "Lost Cause" on the minds of those citizens resentful of the federal government.

Comment: I think you need to have a lot of power/control over people in order to "imprint" their minds...

Comment: @einpoklum So you think that most people are independent-minded enough that demagogues or advertising execs can't easily imprint something on their minds?  I'd say that was just adorable except that the very example in front of you is the Confederate flag.

Answer (score 0):

Merriam-Webster defines "promulgate" as "to make (an idea, belief, etc.) known to many people".

Comment: Also "inculcate", defined by Merriam-Webster as "to cause (something) to be learned by (someone) by repeating it again and again"